# Why does my scrapy ItemLoader fail?

Tags: scrapy

I have a very simple web spider to crawl for some [football team data](http://sports.qq.com/d/f_teams/1/42/). So far I'm just interested in some metadata on the top of the page.
[image: team metadata] 
I tried to use scrapy ItemLoader to retrieve data from the page. But it doesn't work. Only I can get the first field. What did I miss?

```
ft = FootballTeamItem()
    sel = Selector(text = response.text)
    headerLoader = ItemLoader(ft,  selector= sel)
    # headerLoader.add_xpath('name',  '//h2[@class="team-logo"]/strong/text()')
    headerLoader.add_xpath('league','//div[contains(@class, "intro-con team-con")]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a/text()')
    headerLoader.add_xpath('coach', '//div[contains(@class, "intro-con team-con")]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()')
    headerLoader.add_xpath('city',  '//div[contains(@class, "intro-con team-con")]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/text()')
    headerLoader.add_xpath('start', '//div[contains(@class, "intro-con team-con")]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/text()')
    headerLoader.add_xpath('court', '//div[contains(@class, "intro-con team-con")]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()')
    headerLoader.load_item()
```

I tried different ways to construct ItemLoader, with response directly or like this, using a selector instance. But it still didn't work.
The interesting thing is that the code segment runs well without scrapy. But it always fail while running within a scrapy project.

Comment: Can you share code for your definition of `FootballTeamItem`, your spider callback and maybe some logs showing how and where _"fail while running within a scrapy project."_?

Answer (score 0):

You need a period at the beginning of your xpath to treat it as relative to you 'sel' element.